# Amoeba-shaped controls with SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath

I am new to SpriteKit, and I am trying to create a distorted circle that acts like "amoeba". What I am trying to do is to use SKShapeNode initialised with with UIBezierPath created over 8-10 points on a circle with some randomness (something like):

```
    let theta : Double  =  (Double(i) * Double.pi / 180.0) * (36.0 + Double.random(in: -1...1))
    let radius : CGFloat =  CGFloat(100.0 + Double.random(in: 0...20))
    let a = CGFloat(cos(theta)) * radius
    let b = CGFloat(sin(theta)) * radius
```

This part works, but then, I am starting to build the path using addCurve() method and the shapes come out really ugly - probably because I don't fully understand how the method works and what should I use for control points.

Appreciate if you have any better ideas or help me with using addCurve() in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've done - posting as it might be useful to someone, parameters could be tweaked to your liking.

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let numPoints = Int.random(in: 5...25)
    let totalPoints = numPoints * 3
    var pt : [CGPoint] = Array(repeating: CGPoint(), count: totalPoints)
    var coef = 1.0
    for i : Int in 0..<(totalPoints) {
        let theta  =  (Double(i) * Double.pi / 180.0) * (360.0/Double(totalPoints) + Double.random(in: -1.0...1.0))
        
        coef = (i % 3 == 2 ? 1 : 0.25)
        let radius =  CGFloat(100.0 * coef + Double.random(in: 0...20))
        let a = CGFloat(cos(theta)) * radius
        let b = CGFloat(sin(theta)) * radius
        
        pt[i] = CGPoint(x: a, y: b)
        // the code snippet below is to show the curve and critical points
        let point : SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 5)
        point.fillColor = i % 3 == 0 ? .green : .cyan
        point.position = pt[i]
        point.zPosition = 10
        self.addChild(point)
        // end of code snippet
    }
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.view!.bounds.minX + pt[0].x, y: self.view!.bounds.minY + pt[0].y))
    for i in 1...numPoints{
        path.addCurve(to: pt[(i * 3) % (totalPoints)],
                      controlPoint1: pt[(i * 3 - 1)],
                      controlPoint2: pt[(i * 3 - 2)])
    }
    path.close()
    let amoeba = SKShapeNode(path: path.cgPath)
    amoeba.strokeColor = .orange
    self.addChild(amoeba)
```